# Streamlit With Pyinstaller giving me error

Tags: pyinstaller, streamlit

I have a streamlit app which is running fine when I "streamlit run myapp.py" without any errors. But when I create an exe using pyinstaller, and run the exe, I get an error "Bad message format, Tried to use SessionInfo before it was initialized".In console the error is

```
ERROR:asyncio:Exception in callback AppSession._on_scriptrunner_event.<locals>.<lambda>() at streamlit\runtime\app_session.py:473
handle: <Handle AppSession._on_scriptrunner_event.<locals>.<lambda>() at streamlit\runtime\app_session.py:473>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
  File "streamlit\runtime\app_session.py", line 473, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._handle_scriptrunner_event_on_event_loop(
  File "streamlit\runtime\app_session.py", line 543, in _handle_scriptrunner_event_on_event_loop
    self._create_new_session_message(page_script_hash)
  File "streamlit\runtime\app_session.py", line 660, in _create_new_session_message
    imsg.is_hello = self._script_data.is_hello
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

The app_session.py line 468-477 is:

```
This is generally called from the sender ScriptRunner's script thread.
We forward the event on to _handle_scriptrunner_event_on_event_loop,
which will be called on the main thread.
"""
self._event_loop.call_soon_threadsafe(
    lambda: self._handle_scriptrunner_event_on_event_loop(
        sender, event, forward_msg, exception, client_state, page_script_hash
    )
)
```

Whenever I make a change in ui I get this same error, but everything works as it should.

To run streamlit app in pyinstaller, I created a .spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

a = Analysis(
    ['myapp.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[
        (
            "./venv/Lib/site-packages/altair/vegalite/v5/schema/vega-lite-schema.json",
            "./altair/vegalite/v5/schema/"
        ),
        (
            "./venv/Lib/site-packages/",
            "."
        ),
        (
            "./*.py",
            "."
        ),
    ],
    hiddenimports=[
        "streamlit",
        "streamlit-extras"
    ],
    hookspath=['./hooks'],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    [],
    exclude_binaries=True,
    name='myapp',
    debug=True,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
coll = COLLECT(
    exe,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    name='my_app',
)
```